# Expression Blend: How to create User Control with dynamic headline?

Tags: properties, user-controls, expression-blend

I created a UserControl and added a "label" asset. I gave this label a default content property. If I include this UserControl in my projekt, how can I achieve to edit the content property in the properties window? I want to have a behaviour like the TabItem: There is a "Header" option under Properties->CommonProperties where you can define your own header.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your UserControl codebehind class MyUserControl.cs you'll need to add a public property and you're done, the property will be visible and editable via Expression Blend attributes panel.

```
public string MyProperty {  
    get { return this.label.Text;}  
    set { this.label.Text = value; } 
}
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful or would you need more assistance?

Comment: When I add this property to my `VocabularyItemUserControl`, I can see it under `Miscellaneous` section of the `Properties`.. but only *on the screen into which I am inserting `VIUC`*. (As shown on last image of https://fragiledevelopment.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/exposing-properties-in-expression-blend/) however when I am openinig `VIUC.xaml` directly, it doesn't appear under `Common Properties` section (as shown on the link above in section 5.). Is there a way to see the property? (I am on Blend for VS2013 Prof. v12.. update 4)...